# What are the exact requirements to get DOM Templates working in VueJS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vuejs2

I've tried defining my templates in several ways and they all fail with different errors. I've used a single root `<div>` tag within each examples as the console keeps suggesting. For testing, it's just a simple:

```
<div>hello it's me</div>
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Script tag: **Component template requires a root element, rather than just text: hello it's me**

  ```
  <script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
    <div>hello it's me</div>
  </script>
  ```
- Template tag **Cannot find element: #my-template**

  ```
  <template id="my-template">
    <div>hello it's me</div>
  </template>`
  ```
- Script with Template tag: (no console errors, but also **not visible!**)

  ```
  <script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
    <template>
      <div>hello it's me</div>
    </template>
  </script>
  ```
- Script with Template (ID'ed) tag: **Cannot find template: #my-template**

  ```
  <script type="text/x-template">
  <template id="my-template">
      <div>hello it's me</div>
  </template>
  </script>
  ```

What's the proper way to use DOM templates? Also, does the template tags have to appear within the DOM `<head>`, start of `<body>`, end of `<body>`, or somewhere else in particular?

Thanks!

Comment: In bullet and numbered lists, you have to indent code fragments 8 spaces in order to get them to show up properly here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, just realized after I posted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so don't have all your js code but there are two parts to a vue application.

1. Vue instance, this is mounted onto a dom node.  The id goes on some html element in your html
2. Your components that are part of the vue instance application

So for example, lets say you have an index.html file, you would mount vue in this way.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='app'></div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript">
  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  })
</script>
```

This tells vue to create an instance and attach it to your dom.

The second part is to add components to your vue. This is much better performed using webpack, but you can do it manually like this.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>

<script>
  foo = Vue.component('foo',{
    template: '<div>I am a real component!</div>'
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<div><foo></foo></div>',
    components: [foo]
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Aah! Ok so maybe I was misunderstanding how its used with template ID references on the DOM - does it absolutely have to use something like webpack to bundle the templates? No way of doing it via standard HTML files? Just curious though, it probably makes more sense I learn webpack since I'm running a custom node app and all, but I thought for sure vanilla HTML could be recognized by Vue.

Comment: What i put above should just run if you put it in an html file, no webpack necessary. Webpack is just there for if you end up doing more complex things and want to render the single file components like you mentioned above.  If you go that route i recommend using vue-cli to generate a webpack template.